# How to propagate uncertainty to a user defined function using python

Tags: python, numpy, pymc, uncertainty

I would like to propagate uncertainty using python. This is relatively easy for simple functions via the uncertainties package. However, it is not that obvious to achieve the same with a user defined function. What follows is an example of what I am trying to do.

```
import mcerp as err
import numpy as np


def mult_func(x,xm ,a):
    x[x==0.] = 1e-20
    v = (1.-(xm/x)**a) * (x > xm)
    v[np.isnan(v)] = 0.
    return v


def intg(e,f,cut,s):
    t = mult_func(e,cut,s)
    res = np.trapz(t*f,e)  
    return res  

x=np.linspace(0,1,10000)
y=np.exp(x)

m=0.
mm=0.
N=100000  
for i in range(0,N):
    cut=np.random.normal(0.21,0.02)
    stg=np.random.normal(1.1,0.1)
    v=intg(x,y,cut,stg)
    m=m+v
    mm=mm+v*v



print("avg. %10.5E +/- %10.5E fixed %10.5E"%(m/N,np.sqrt((mm/N-(m/N)**2)),intg(x,y,0.21,1.1)))
```

What is done above is just random sampling of two parameters and calculating the mean and the variance. I am not sure however, how much this brute-force method is adequate. I could use the law of large numbers and to try estimate how many trials `N` are needed to get a certain value `(P=1-1/(N*k**2))` to be around `k` times standard deviations around the true mean.

In principle what I wrote could work. However, my assumption is that being such a flexible language with many powerful packages, python could do this task much more effectively. I was thinking about `uncertainties`, `mcerp` and `pymc`. Due to my limited experience using those packages, I am not sure how to proceed.

EDIT:
MY original example was not that much informative, this is why I decided to do a new example which actually works to illustrate my idea.

Comment: why does this question has the tag 'pymc' ?

Answer (score -1):

Numpy supports arrays of arbitrary numeric types. However, not all functions are supporter for arbitrary numeric types.

In this case, both `numpy.exp` and `trapz` are not supported.

Note that the uncertanties module contains the `unumpy` package. `numpy.exp` has a replacement here: `uncertainties.unumpy.exp`

We, define trapz  as a [ufunc](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.12.0/reference/ufuncs.html).

Check it out here!

```
a=un.ufloat(0.3,0.01)
b=un.ufloat(1.2,0.071)



def sample_func(a: un.UFloat, b: un.UFloat) -> np.ndarray:
    x=np.linspace(0,a,100)
    y = un.unumpy.exp(x)
    return utrapz(y, x)

def utrapz(y: np.ndarray, x: np.ndarray) -> np.ndarray:
    Δx = x[1:]-x[:-1]
    avg_y = (y[1:]+y[:-1])/2
    return (Δx*avg_y)


print(sample_func(a, b))
```

OUT:

```
[0.00026601240063021264+/-nan 0.0005935120815465686+/-6.429403852670308e-06
 0.0006973604419223405+/-3.888235103342809e-06 ...,
 0.002095505706899622+/-6.503985178118233e-05
 0.0021019968633076134+/-6.545802781649068e-05
 0.0021084415802710295+/-6.587387316821736e-05]
```

Comment: `np.exp()` is not the same as `**`. `np.exp()` is the exponential function.

Comment: Oh, that's a pretty significant error. Let me fix that!